# Reducing system of 10 inequalities

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities, findinstance

I have the following system of inequalities of real variables

```
sys = 0.383706 x1 + 0.720204 x2 + 1.4568 x3 - 0.000244875 y >   0 && -0.0941312 x1 - 0.176681 x2 - 0.357383 x3 + 0.0000592689 y >   0 && 1.41819 x1 + 3.079 x2 + 2.53801 x3 - 0.00182772 y >   0 && -0.00258971 x1 - 0.00562247 x2 - 0.00463458 x3 +    3.93843*10^-6 y > 0 &&  0.129511 x1 + 0.214698 x2 + 0.286739 x3 - 0.0000795243 y >   0 && -0.660462 x1 - 1.09489 x2 - 1.46227 x3 + 0.000405426 y > 0 &&  0.351966 x1 + 3.44019 x2 + 7.59863 x3 + 0.00257072 y >   0 && -0.00265509 x1 - 0.0259514 x2 - 0.0573209 x3 -    0.0000199557 y > 0 &&  1.34471 x1 + 2.58639 x2 + 3.39561 x3 + 0.0000742173 y >   0 && -0.0314846 x1 - 0.0605571 x2 - 0.079504 x3 - 1.69328*10^-6 y >   0
```

I want to `Reduce` the system in order to see if it admits solutions or not. However, the command `Reduce` takes too much time and gets stuck. How can you check if this system admits solutions?

I have tried with `FindInstance[sys,{x1,x2,x3,y},Reals]` which returns `{}`. However, I am not sure this is a fully proof that the system does not admit solution. Indeed, If I run the command on a subsystem of inequalities I experience the following behaviour

```
FindInstance[sys[[1 ;; 4]], {x1, x2, x3, y}, Reals]
(* {} *)
```

but If I ask for more instances, Mathematica found the points

```
FindInstance[sys[[1 ;; 4]], {x1, x2, x3, y}, Reals, 2]
(*{{x1 -> -33., x2 -> 13.5619, x3 -> 1.98727, y -> 0.255564}, {x1 -> -51., x2 -> 20.9595, x3 -> 3.07117, y -> 0.601467}}*)
```

So, the subsystem [[1;;4]] admits at least a solution. I have run `FindInstance[sys, {x1, x2, x3, y}, Reals, 2]` for all the night and got the output `{}`. Still, is this a proof that the system does not admits solution?

Comment: `Reduce[Rationalize[sys, 2^-12], {x1, x2, x3, y}, Reals]` gives `False`.

Comment: and `RegionIntersection @@ (ImplicitRegion[#,  {x1, x2, x3,   y}] & /@ (List @@ sys))`  gives `EmptyRegion[4]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Reduce[Rationalize[sys, 2^-12], {x1, x2, x3, y}, Reals] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.24878, False}

```
RegionIntersection @@ (ImplicitRegion[#, {x1, x2, x3, y}] & /@ (List @@ sys)) // 
   RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.0152, EmptyRegion[4]}